# Может ли SQL Server при вставке записей менять порядок их значений?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Используем SQL Server 2012.

Допустим, у нас есть такой тип:

```
create type dbo.user (
  id int, 
  name varchar,
  age int,
)
```

И такая хранимая процедура

```
create procedure dbo.InsertUsers
  @Users dbo.user readonly
as
begin
  insert into dbo.Users 
  select * from @Users
end
```

Может ли в таком случае оператор вида `INSERT INTO SELECT * FROM @Users` в хранимой процедуре вставлять данные не в том порядке, в котором они передаются в `@Users`?

Comment: А кто или что ему запретит? не экономьте байты...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то речь о порядке *строк*.

Нет, порядок *строк* не гарантирован, он может быть произвольным.

---

А вот порядок *столбцов* (*колонок*), насколько я знаю, всегда будет таким, какой был установлен при создании таблицы.

Однако, если используется *объединение* (join) нескольких таблиц, то тут с порядком *колонок* несколько сложнее. В таком случае его лучше указывать вручную.

Answer (score 2):

В соответствии со стандартом SQL, столбцы в таблице не "упорядочены".

В результате, select * не заставляет столбцы возвращаться в определенном порядке.

Как правило, каждая RDBMS имеет своего рода "по умолчанию" порядок (обычно порядок, в который столбцы были добавлены в таблицу), но порядок их возврата все равно не гарантирован.

Поэтому, нужно явным образом перечислять столбцы в том порядке, в котором вы хотите.

Comment: Гм, а можно ссылку на стандарт, где это сказано? Имхо, столбцы все-таки упорядочены, а вот строки - нет.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov увы, нет возможности и желания это делать:) но раз вопрос касался sql-server, то будем доверять его докам - `Не следует предполагать, что SELECT * будет возвращать все столбцы в ожидаемом порядке, основанном на порядке их определения в таблице. Всегда указывайте столбцы в запросах и приложениях по именам в том порядке, в котором они должны следовать.` - взято тут https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/tables/change-column-order-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017